# Derivative of arctan

Tags: derivatives

What is the derivative of $\arctan (x^2)$? I got this problem while doing an integration; the integration was as follows: $$\int\frac{x \arctan x^2}{1+x^4}dx$$

Comment: Just use the chain rule....

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \arctan x^2 = \frac{d\arctan x^2}{dx^2} \frac{dx^2}{dx} = \frac{1}{1+(x^2)^2} \frac{d}{dx} x^2 = \frac{2x}{1+x^4}
$$

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me a lot.